# Multiprocessing.Process not starting without any error

Tags: python

Below is my demo:

```
Thread xxx:
    import xxx
    import xxxx

    def test_process1(hostname,proxy_param):
        # just never run
        try:                             # breakpoint 0
            with open("/xxx","w+") as f: # breakpoint 1
                f.write("something")
        except Exception as e:
            pass # just never run  breakpoint 3
    def test():
        try:
            a = Process(target=test_process1, args=(hostname,proxy_param))
            a.start()
            a.join() # you are blocking here. test_process1 not working and never quit
        except Exception as e: 
            pass # breakpoint 4
```

function `test_process1` just never run. No error, No breakpoint.

The test function code is in a big project, here is a demo.

Comment: How do you know that it never runs ? also can you provide us with any stack traces etc to help us with your issues, perhaps use something like https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_interpreter

Comment: Please, provide the full code you are running. I can guess, probably, your script ends with the command `a.start()` thus the main thread stops immediately after that and the child thread has no time to start. Add `a.join()` after `a.start()`, maybe it is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Hope! this piece of code helps.

Workers list will get divided based on the number of processes in use.

Sample Code with ManagerList.

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
from multiprocessing import Pool,Pipe
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Manager

def child_process(child_conn,output_list,messenger):
    input_recvd = messenger["input"]
    output_list.append(input_recvd)
    print(input_recvd)
    child_conn.close()

def parent_process(number_of_process=2):
    workers_inputs = [{"input":"hello"}, {"input":"world"}]
    with Manager() as manager:
        processes        = []
        output_list      = manager.list()  # <-- can be shared between processes.
        parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
        for single_id_dict in workers_inputs:
            pro_obj             = Process(target=child_process, args=(child_conn,output_list,single_id_dict))  # Passing the list
            pro_obj.start()
            processes.append(pro_obj)
        for p in processes:
            p.join()
        output_list = [single_feature for single_feature in output_list]
    return output_list

parent_process()
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
hello

world

['hello', 'world']
```

ManagerList is useful to get the output from various parallel process it's like an inbuilt Queue Mechanism with easy to use and safe from deadlocks.